# Laravel 9 `groupBy` С учетом `limit` для каждой группы

Tags: mysql, laravel

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

По сути я хочу взать для каждогй группы определенное каличество строк.

К примеру для каждой группы по `industry_id` взять 2.

Вот пример для ՝count = 2՝

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот тот самый простой запрос на `Laravel Eloquent`

```
$response = $this->model->whereIn('industry_id', $industryIds)->get();
if($count > 0) {
    $response->groupBy('industry_id', function ($query) use($count) {
        return $query->limit($count);
    });
}
return $response->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Но он не хочет работать как я ожидал.

Кто столкнулся с такой проблемой? И как решить эту проблему без `Колхоза` )))

Comment: *По сути я хочу взать для каждогй группы определенное каличество строк.*  - для какой группы, если вы по ид записи тащите (whereIn)?

Comment: @InDevX обновил вопрос. мосмотрите.

Comment: задача про оконные функции, а не про группировку. Какая версия mysql ?

Comment: @teran Mysql 8.0, php 8.1, laravel 9

Comment: @teran все в одной таблице. нету `join`

Comment: ну вот и почитайте как `row_number()` в ларавель перенести. Основной запрос с `row_number() over (partition by industry_id) будет и потом его отфильтровать по нужному числу строк

Comment: @teran спасибо. сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: @teran вот прописал запрос так `SELECT
  id, industry_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY industry_id) AS RowNum
FROM
  emails
WHERE industry_id IN ( 1200, 1201) AND RowNum < 3;`, здесь ругается что нету переменной `RowNum`.  Но если вынуть его ис `where`  то таблица результата нормально показывает с калонкой  `RowNum`.  что не так делаю не понятно.

Comment: `where` выполняете до селекта, поэтому использовать там выражения селекта нельзя. Запихайте запрос в CTE или в производную таблицу, и там уже отфильтруйте.

Comment: @teran Хотел без производной таблицы. Что бы все это нормально мог запихать в `laravel eloquent`.)))

Comment: @teran Вот так работает. но хотел без него.  `WITH TmpEmails AS(
 SELECT
  id, industry_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY industry_id) AS RowNum
FROM
  emails
WHERE industry_id IN (
    1200,
    1201
  )
)
SELECT  id, industry_id, RowNum
FROM    TmpEmails
WHERE   RowNum < 3;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решается с помощью `row_number()`.

С перва запрашиваем все результаты с `row_number()`.

```
$response = $this->model->select('*', DB::raw('row_number() over (partition by industry_id) AS rowCnt'))->whereIn('industry_id', $industryIds)->get();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поскольку `laravel` может работать с коллекциями и после `->get()`.

Можем сделать так.

```
$response->where('rowCnt', '<', $count+1);
```

Потому что уже в коллекции есть колонка с номерами с именем `rowCnt`.

Дальше уже мы получаем результаты с лимитом по каждой группе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и весь простенький код )))

```
$response = $this->model->select('*', DB::raw('row_number() over (partition by industry_id) AS rowCnt'))->whereIn('industry_id', $industryIds)->get();
if($count > 0) {
    $response->where('rowCnt', '<', $count+1);
}
return $response->toArray();
```

И особая благодарность пользователю `@teran` за подсказку по какому направлению искать.

Comment: сдается мне, что в такой реализации вы получаете на бэк все записи и уже там фильтруете через коллекции? можно ведь  наверное сделать а-ля `$subquery = .... выборка с row_number ....` а потом сделать `->from($subquery)->where(...)` ?

Comment: @teran Да но проэкт построен с учетом репозиторий. Не могу просто `SQL` запрос впихнуть там. Бизнес логика не позволяет. Потом могут другие базы подключить.